# Force mongodump from secondary server "not master or slaveOk=false"

Tags: mongodb

Trying to export small data set from a mongo server (2.4.3)

The environment has a **primary** and one **secondary** instance, but the secondary shows `slaveOk=false`, and I can't fix/connect to the primary.

Connecting by shell works; auto routes me to secondary and shows warning:

```
assertion:{ $err: "not master and slaveOk=false", code 13435}
```

Can't do any queries unless I do:

```
rs.slaveOk()
```

...that's fine, but works only for the current connection. Once I exit and try do do `mongodump`, I get the same error as above.

```
> mongodump -h myhost:33478 -d database -o /mydir
connected to: myhost:33478 
assertion:{ $err: "not master and slaveOk=false", code 13435}
```

Did not find any option in `mongodump` to force exporting from a server in such a state.

I'm assuming this can be achieved through scripting, but after searching around, could not find anything to switch secondary to "ok" state and executing mongodump with the same connection.

Pardon the ignorance, still very new to Mongo.

Comment: Can you confirm the MongoDB version you are running? If really 2.3.4 then you are on a test build. I would use either 2.4.10 or 2.6.1 which are the latest releases. You should be able to mongodump against a secondary without seeing this.

Comment: My bad, I'm on 2.4.3!

Comment: @JamesWahlin thank you!, after checking the version, I found another secondary in the replica list! I supposed the dev team neglected to inform me about it; I just connected and it IS the primary, no more error!

Answer (score 0):

That means you driver is configured to use Master only and host you gave to mongo connector is a slave.